# Symfony2 FOSRestBundle: Which class to include for codes like HTTP_NO_CONTENT

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I wanna throw an HTTP_NO_CONTENT, but symfony tells me that `ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Codes" from namespace "FOS\Rest\Util". Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?`

I actually did `use FOS\RestBundle\Util\Codes;` in my class.

My call looks like this

```
public function deleteAction($id)
{
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $player = $em->getRepository('xxx')->find($id);

  $em->remove($player);
  $em->flush();

  return $this->view(null, new HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
}
```

Why is it not possible to find that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new HTTP_NO_CONTENT` doesn't make sens here! You've to use  `FOS\RestBundle\Util\Codes` class,

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Util\Codes;
```

and point to the right status code as follow,

```
Codes::HTTP_NO_CONTENT // As HTTP_NO_CONTENT is defined as a constant
```